# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value, confused on query design?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, subquery

I'm hoping some of you can help me with this.  My SQL skills are pretty weak, and there's a major SSIS job at my work that is failing to run now.  It's run fine for 3+ years since I started with no issues, but in the past 48 hours it's failed twice.  The error is as follows:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I've confirmed (as much as I can) that there have been no changes to the database structure/design or anything, but sadly that's about all I can do.  Otherwise this lovely issue falls to me.

I understand the error means I'm getting multiple records back when I should get one, but that's about as much as I understand.

The flow of this job is as follows:  the **ProvUserDefinedDataRotated** table is dropped each night, and then the query below is run immediately after that.

```
SELECT objectinternalid, 
       FaxComments = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                              FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                              WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 75 
                                     AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), 
                     ''), 
       FaxCommentsDate = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                  FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                  WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 76 
                                         AND objectinternalid = 
                                             Q.objectinternalid), '' 
                         ), 
       Specialty = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                            FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                            WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 77 
                                   AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), 
                   ''), 
       DepartmentFullDescript = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                         FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                         WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 78 
                                                AND objectinternalid = 
                                                    Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       Alerts1 = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                          FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                          WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 79 
                                 AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), '') 
       , 
       ProviderStatus = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                 FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                 WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 80 
                                        AND objectinternalid = 
                                            Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       ProviderRole = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                               FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                               WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 81 
                                      AND objectinternalid = 
                      Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       ProfessionalTitle = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                    FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                    WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 82 
                                           AND objectinternalid = 
                                               Q.objectinternalid), 
                           ''), 
       SignatureBlockTitle = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                      FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                      WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 96 
                                             AND objectinternalid = 
                             Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       AlertsUsedWithProfTitles = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                           FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                           WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 
                                                  98 
                                                  AND objectinternalid = 
                                                      Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       ProfTitleAlertDescrpt = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                        FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                        WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 99 
                                               AND objectinternalid = 
                                                   Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       ProviderFullFaxNumber = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                        FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                        WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 102 
                                               AND objectinternalid = 
                                                   Q.objectinternalid), ''), 
       NonEsig = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                          FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                          WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 112 
                                 AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), '') 
       , 
       EsigEWSTrainNotes = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                    FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                    WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 146 
                                           AND objectinternalid = 
                                               Q.objectinternalid), 
                           ''), 
       ESigEWSTrainedDate = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                     FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                     WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 147 
                                            AND objectinternalid = 
                                                Q.objectinternalid), 
                            ''), 
       EPICTrained = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                              FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                              WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 163 
                                     AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), 
                     ''), 
       EPICTrainedDate = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                                  FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                                  WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 164 
                                         AND objectinternalid = 
                                             Q.objectinternalid), '' 
                         ) 
INTO   provuserdefineddatarotated 
FROM   provuserdefineddata Q 
GROUP  BY objectinternalid 
ORDER  BY objectinternalid
```

From my limited understanding, it seems like this query just copies data into the newly created **ProvUserDefinedDataRotated** table after said table is dropped?

I'm confused on what the individual statements like this

```
   FaxComments = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                          FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                          WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 75 
                                 AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), 
                 ''),
```

actually mean though.  I just don't understand at all what's going on in that code. :(

Any explanations on the design of this query and/or guidance on how to troubleshoot this at all would be so appreciated.  I have been googling furiously to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Be reassured that whoever wrote this SQL did a bad job and left a time bomb in it that was going to blow up eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the heart of it, this query is pulling back records from the `provuserdefineddata` table. The driver from this table is the column `objectinternalid` That value is then used to find a match back in the same table based on userdefinedfieldinternalid being of various types.

In this snippet

FaxComments = Isnull ((SELECT value 
                          FROM   provuserdefineddata 
                          WHERE  userdefinedfieldinternalid = 75 
                                 AND objectinternalid = Q.objectinternalid), 
                 ''),

Read that as Get the "value" from the table provuserdefineddata which has a userdefinedfieldinternalid of 75 and matches the objectinternalid from the main table. Oh and if we don't find anytything (isnull) then make it an empty string.

This mechanism assumes there will be zero to one items found. Finding more than one results in the lovely error you have.

So, you're correct in that the code has not changed but something, somewhere has introduced data that should not be there.

How do you resolve it? Without a code change, you need to identify the userdefinedfieldinternalid and objectinternalid combos that show up more than once (for the list of IDs above).

A safer way to resolve it, besides completely refactoring this database design, is to apply a `top 1` or an aggregate `max/min` to the subqueries.

Comment: Thank you, I totally understand this now!  I was able to track down the duplicate records and contact the operational users who created them to resolve!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation of **isNull**: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx.

In short for `isNull(select value ..., '')`

```
if ( the inner select value is null) 
then return '' 
else return value of inner select
```

The problem with your query is, that these subqueries must return one or no value. (That is simply a rule).

In your subqueries you request always the same table. Therefore there must multiple values for one specific `userdefinedfieldinternalid` and `objectinternalid`. Without limiting `userdefinedfieldinternalid` to those values you used you can select the "multi" values with an select like:

```
SELECT userdefinedfieldinternalid, objectinternalid FROM   provuserdefineddata group by userdefinedfieldinternalid, objectinternalid having count(*)>1
```

I hope I got the syntax right for your database management system.